# What was the latest version of google-oauth2 updated?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

We are using the following url for Google OAuth2 v3 now.

- https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
- https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token

But, I confirmed version-up in the latest document(https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer).

- https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/**v2**/auth
- https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/**v4**/token

What was changed?
If possible, we want to update it.

Comment: Looks like `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token/` is now obsolete. (e.g. https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript/issues/43).

Answer (score 1):

This is the third time i think i have seen them change them in the last five years.  Exactly why they change them they never inform us. I would suspect that the new endpoints are OpenIDConnect compliant.

The old ones should continue to work for a while i have not heard anything about them shutting them down.

You can also check the [Discovery document](https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. They should inform this change because we don't know that we should update or not. We will try to update this.